# Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

var money = parseInt(prompt('сумма вклада:'));
var interest = parseInt(prompt("процентная ставка:"));
var years = parseInt(prompt("срок вклада:"));
for(var i=1; i<=years; i++) {
money = money + money + interest / 100;
alert('Прошло лет: ' + i + ', сумма на счету: ' + Math.floor(money));
}
</script>
```

Помогите найти ошибку,не выводиться на экран полученная сумма за каждый год

Comment: money + money + interest / 100, может второй + на * заменить

Comment: вроде все работает http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKVNWp